# MySQL performance difference between local and prod with large text column

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I'm trying to figure out what could account for the very large performance difference between my dev environment (5 year old laptop) and our stage server (azure cloud). The table in question is a log table of web service requests for a service that processes XML. One of the columns in the table is the XML passed to the web service.

On my local computer it basically doesn't matter how many rows are in the table; performance is great. On the deployed server if there are more than a couple hundred rows then performance starts tanking quickly. A "select count(*)" on this table when it has 2000 rows in it will take 0.0017 seconds locally but close to 20 on the server. Even a simple insert of a new row takes a significant amount of time; on the order of whole seconds.

I found this article while researching the problem [explanation of MySQL block performance](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/11/handling-long-textsblobs-in-innodb-1-to.html). That makes sense to me and I'd be happy to implement the 1-to-1 solution but I don't want to do it until I understand why it's working fine locally and tanking on the server.

Are there some MySQL setting variables I can check to find the differences? I'd really like to get my local computer to have the same performance issue as the deployed so I can validate that the fix will work.

EDIT:
The create table queries are identical. MySQL versions are 5.7.23 and 5.7.22. I did notice that the buffer is 16x bigger on my local. Gonna try and get the server updated to the setting my local has and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on both machines; show us both and highlight the differences.  Also, state what versions  of MySQL are in each machine.

Comment: Also, compare `innodb_buffer_pool_size` between them.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I checked the settings you recommended.  Seems like the buffer pool size is probably it. Gonna try and get the server updated and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was updating the buffer pool size like Rick suggested.